# Upload photo in project and db - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, image-uploading

I need some help with upload. I want to insert a product into the db. The product has 3 pictures. I want the picture to be uploaded into a specific folder in the project, and the path to be entered into the db. 
The folder where I want to upload the photos is: /public/css/img

My Db looks like this: I will put an example added manually in db.

id | title |price|category_id| images1       | images2|         | images3| etc.
    1 |Sofa   |324.0   5        |/css/img/1.jpg |/css/img/2.jpg    |/css/img/3.jpg

This is my view addProductModal.blade.php -> Is a modal with form.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalFormaddproduct" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" id="route">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Inchide</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Adauga Subcategorie</h4>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal Body -->
            <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center;">
                <p class="statusMsg"></p>
                <form role="form" action="{{route('addproduct')}}" method="post">
                    {{csrf_field()}}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Nume</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control  text-center" name="name" placeholder="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Pret</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control  text-center" name="price" placeholder="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.row -->
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Subcategoria:</label>
                            <select style="text-align-last:center" class="form-control text-center" name="category_id">
                                @foreach($categories as $category)
                                    @foreach($category->subcategories as $subcategory)
                                        <option value="{{$subcategory->id}}">{{$subcategory->category}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Descriere</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control  text-center" name="description" placeholder="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Marime</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" name="size" placeholder="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Material</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control  text-center" name="material" placeholder="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Cantitate</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control  text-center" name="quantity" placeholder="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Recomandat:</label>
                                <select style="text-align-last:center" class="form-control text-center" name="hot">
                                    <option value="0">Nerecomandat</option>
                                    <option value="1">Recomandat</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Imagine 1:</label>
                                    <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Upload1" name="submit1">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" name="_token">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Imagine 2:</label>
                                    <input type="file" name="file2" id="file2">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Upload2" name="submit2">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" name="_token">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Imagine 3:</label>
                                    <input type="file" name="file3" id="file3">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Upload3" name="submit3">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" name="_token">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" style="background: gainsboro; border-radius: 8px" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Inchide</button>
                            <button type="submit" style="background: #10D47D; border-radius: 8px" class="btn btn-primary">Adauga</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Route is `Route::post('/products/add', 'AdminController@addproduct')->name('addproduct');`

Controller: AdminController.php

```
public function addproduct(Request $request)
    {
        $product = new Product();
        $product->title = $request->name;
        $product->price = $request->price;
        $product->category_id =  $request->category_id;
        $product->description = $request->description;
        $product->size = $request->size;
        $product->material = $request->material;
        $product->quantity = $request->quantity;
        $product->hot = $request->hot;
        $product->images1 = $request->file1;
        $product->images2 = $request->file2;
        $product->images3 = $request->file3;


         if (Input::hasFile('file1','file2','file3')) {

        echo 'Uploaded';
        $file = Input::file('file1','file2','file3');
        $file->move('uploads', $file->getClientOriginalName());
        echo '';
    }
        $product->save();
        return redirect(route('adminproducts'))->with('success', 'The Product was added');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add into your form:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

to make sure you can upload a file like so:

```
<form role="form" action="{{route('addproduct')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: after I added enctype, the path entered in dB is: E:\Instalate\xampp\tmp\php9D38.tmp. The problem is that in the product details view the picture is not displayed. How can i change the path to: \public\css\img\.jpg ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is any reason not to use some maintained library but write all the functionality yourself. I would recommend you to take a look on: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary

Comment: it's a bit complicated for me. I'm a beginner :)

Comment: Sure, so you can use to solution below :) But when your page come up a little bit more difficult and you will want to use more complex solution and manipulate with the images and the files stored to your app then remember the link and surly take a look on it in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
  public function addproduct(Request $request)
    {
        $product = new Product();
        $product->title = $request->name;
        $product->price = $request->price;
        $product->category_id = $request->category_id;
        $product->description = $request->description;
        $product->size = $request->size;
        $product->material = $request->material;
        $product->quantity = $request->quantity;
        $product->hot = $request->hot;
        $file1 = Input::file('file1');
        $file2 = Input::file('file2');
        $file3 = Input::file('file3');
        $filename1 = $file1->getClientOriginalName();
        $filename2 = $file2->getClientOriginalName();
        $filename3 = $file3->getClientOriginalName();
        $file1 = $file1->move(public_path().'/img', $filename1);
        $file2 = $file2->move(public_path().'/img', $filename2);
        $file3 = $file3->move(public_path().'/img', $filename3);
        $product->images1 = '/img/'.$filename1;
        $product->images2 = '/img/'.$filename2;
        $product->images3 = '/img/'.$filename3;
        $product->save();
        return redirect(route('adminproducts'))->with('success', 'Produsul a fost creat');
    }
```